# Boxplot in R for Factor Data

Tags: r, boxplot

I would like to create a boxplot for my project. So I'm working on a world happiness dataset which contains Region as factors and happiness.score as numeric values, etc. I want to compare the mean happiness score between regions and here is what I wrote:

```
ggplot(data=happiness, mapping = aes(x = Region, y = Happiness.Score))  + geom_boxplot()
```

But the output is weird as below:
[image]

Could anyone please give some suggestions?

Comment: Your code seems to be correct.  It could be the data i.e. check with `class(happiness$Happiness.Score)`.  Please check with `iris` `ggplot(data = iris, mapping = aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) + geom_boxplot()`

Comment: The problem is that `Happiness.Score` is a character or factor vector instead of actual numbers. Try `ggplot(data=happiness, mapping = aes(x = Region, y = as.numeric(as.character(Happiness.Score)) )) + geom_boxplot()`

Comment: Thank you akrun and Allan, I just figured it out that happiness.score is character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could happen if the 'y' variable is `factor`.  Convert it to `numeric` from `factor` and it should work

```
happiness$Happiness.Score <- as.numeric(as.character(happiness$Happiness.Score))
ggplot(data=happiness, mapping = aes(x = Region, y = Happiness.Score))  + 
               geom_boxplot()
```

---

Reproducible example with

```
data(iris)
ggplot(data = iris, mapping = aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) + 
      geom_boxplot()
```

Now, check with the 'Sepal.Length' as `factor`

```
ggplot(data = iris, mapping = aes(x = Species, y = factor(Sepal.Length))) + 
           geom_boxplot()
```